# postgres14 on ubuntu streaming replication to a freebsd

Tags: postgresql, replication

I am trying to setup my `postgres streaming replication` to a freebsd machine. The problem is that both use different `postgres.conf` files with different system locations.

I can run `pg_basebackup` with no issues but can't run the server on freebsd (slave machine) for various reasons such as different paths setup on the `postgres.conf` coming from the master running on Ubuntu.

Is it even possible to do it? any ideas how to achieve this?

thanks

Comment: Streaming replication between different operating systems is not a good idea, even if the hardware is the same.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe that's what I thought. Thanks for the comment

Comment: This seems like a bad idea, but I don't see how those things you mention have anything to do with it.  If something in postgresql.conf needs to be different, then make it different.